# Comparing Timezone Facing Issue

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm comparing timezone and not working as expected.

```
$input_start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2017-01-17 08:00:00');
$input_start_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

$input_end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2017-01-17 20:00:00');
$input_end_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

$current_date = new DateTime("Asia/Seoul");

print_r($input_start_time);
print_r($input_end_time);
print_r($current_date);

while($input_start_time <= $input_end_time)
{
    if($input_start_time <= $current_date)
    {
        echo $input_start_time->format('h:i A').PHP_EOL;
    }
    $input_start_time->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
}
```

Over here I'm saving data within `UTC` format and need to compare that within another `timezone` i.e. `Asia/Seoul` but I might be doing it in a wrong way it seems. Currently it gives me an output like as

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-01-17 07:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-01-17 19:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2017-01-17 18:19:03.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Asia/Seoul
)
07:00 AM
07:30 AM
08:00 AM
08:30 AM
09:00 AM
```

Everything is fine but I need to get result somewhat like as

```
07:00 AM
07:30 AM
08:00 AM
08:30 AM
09:00 AM
.....
06:00 PM
06:30 PM
```

What's wrong I'm doing over here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've managed to solve my answer but other answers are too acceptable. Right now I'm using extra variable for comparing the `datetime` object like as

```
$input_start_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2017-01-17 08:00:00');
$input_start_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

$input_end_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','2017-01-17 20:00:00');
$input_end_time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

$current_date_timezone = new DateTime("Asia/Seoul");
$current_data = new DateTime($current_date_timezone->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // get the `Asia/Seoul` current time within UTC and comparing this object

while($input_start_time <= $input_end_time)
{
    if($input_start_time <= $current_date)
    {
        echo $input_start_time->format('h:i A').PHP_EOL;
    }
    $input_start_time->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
}
```